# Get unions and intersections of list of datetime ranges python

Tags: python, datetime, union, intersection

I have two lists of `datetime` ranges.
eg.

```
l1 = [(datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 3, 0, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 9, 0, 0))]
l2 = [(datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 4, 0, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 7, 0, 0))]
```

And I want to get the union of `l1` and `l2`.
The desired outputs are:

```
union = [(datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 4, 0, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 9, 0, 0))]
intersection = [(datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 3, 0, 0)), (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 7, 0, 0))]
```

Real data may not be this perfectly aligned.

Comment: cant you make them to set and then perform union and intersection?

Comment: This would work if these were raw values, however here author treats list items as ranges.

Comment: Are you interested only in hour precision? Time is not that discrete in general.

Comment: @AChampion The tuples in the list are intervals of an event happening. So l1 contains intervals that event 1 happened while l2 is for event 2.

Comment: @Yakuza nope. Any precision

Comment: Do you need to test all tuples against each other or just index 0 of `l1` with index 0 of `l2`? You mention not perfectly aligned for the real data - what does this mean?

Comment: So for input [(2018-08-29 1:30:30, 2018-08-29 3:40:30)], [(2018-08-29 1:45:00, 2018-08-29 2:45:00)] what output is expected?

Comment: @AChampion yes, I need to check everyone against each other. and the union might not have the same length as l1 and l2.

Comment: @Yakuza [(2018-08-29 1:30:00, 2018-08-29 3:40:30)]

Comment: How are you determining not to include in the results e.g. `l1[1]` against `l1[0]` would have a union of `2 - 9` - why is that not in the result set?

Comment: @AChampion because `l1[1]` and `l1[0]` dont have intersections to merge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of union and intersection for the date range can be simply described as :-

*Union:*

```
In []:
from itertools import product
[(min(s1, s2), max(e1, e2)) for (s1, e1), (s2, e2) in product(l1, l2) if s1 <= e2 and e1 >= s2]

Out[]:
[(datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 4, 0)),
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 5, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 9, 0))]
```

*Intersection:*

```
In []:
[(max(s1, s2), min(e1, e2)) for (s1, e1), (s2, e2) in product(l1, l2) if s1 <= e2 and e1 >= s2]

Out[]:
[(datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 3, 0)),
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 29, 7, 0))]
```

You can replace `<=` and `>=` with `<` and `>` if they strictly have to overlap and not just touch.

Comment: One more thing there is a range that doesn't overlap with any other range then it should be included in the union.

Comment: @DawitAbate that is a different question, feel free to ask another question. Hopefully this has helped you with this question.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108651/4998) is very useful for what you're asking, as it can compact an array of overlapping ranges:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def consolidate(intervals):
    sorted_intervals = sorted(intervals, key=itemgetter(0))

    if not sorted_intervals:  # no intervals to merge
        return

    # low and high represent the bounds of the current run of merges
    low, high = sorted_intervals[0]

    for iv in sorted_intervals[1:]:
        if iv[0] <= high:  # new interval overlaps current run
            high = max(high, iv[1])  # merge with the current run
        else:  # current run is over
            yield low, high  # yield accumulated interval
            low, high = iv  # start new run

    yield low, high  # end the final run
```

Union of `l1` and `l2` is simply the consolidation of all ranges in both `l1` and `l2`:

```
def union(l1, l2):
    return consolidate([*l1, *l2])
```

Intersection of `l1` and `l2` is adequately done by AChampion's code (if there is any overlap between any range in `l1` and any range in `l2`, that overlap deserves to be in the result), but it could lead to fragmentation of ranges; we can use this same function to join the adjacent or overlapping ranges:

```
from itertools import product

def intersection(l1, l2):
    result = ((max(s1, s2), min(e1, e2)) for (s1, e1), (s2, e2) in product(l1, l2) if s1 < e2 and e1 > s2)
    return consolidate(result)
```

An example:

```
l1 = [(1, 7), (4, 8), (10, 15), (20, 30), (50, 60)]
l2 = [(3, 6), (8, 11), (15, 20)]
print(list(union(l1, l2)))         # [(1, 30), (50, 60)]
print(list(intersection(l1, l2)))  # [(3, 6), (10, 11)]
```

(The example uses integers for clarity, but it works with any comparable type. Specifically, for OP's `l1` and `l2`, the code yields OP's desired `datetime` results.)